# how to use jstl arraylist in jsp

Tags: database, eclipse, jsp, jstl

I have problem to show data in jsp page with help of jstl. there is code and also error that i have got ;
    my JSP PAGE  is

```
        <body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>UserId </th>
                    <th>First Name </th>
                    <th>Last Name </th>
                    <th>DOB </th>
                    <th>Email Id </th>
                    <th colspan="2" >Action</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" >
             <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.userid}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.lastName}" /></td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" value="${user.dob}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.email}" /></td>
                    <td><a href="UserController?action=edit&userId=<c:out value="${user.userid}"/>">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a href="UserController?action=delete&userId=<c:out value="${user.userid}"/>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>

                </c:forEach>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><a href="UserController?action=insert">Add User</a>
```

this code where we fetch ALLUSERLIST IS :
    public ArrayList getAllUsers()
    {

```
ArrayList<User> USER = new ArrayList<User>();
    try
    {
        iduQuery = "select * from user";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery(iduQuery);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            User user =new User();

            user.setUserid(rs.getString("userid"));
            System.out.println("USER ID :    " + user);
            user.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
            user.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
            user.setDob( new java.sql.Date(rs.getDate("dob").getTime()));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            USER.add(user);
        }

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error : GetALLUSER   " + e);
    }
    return USER;
```

}

Where we call jsp page :

```
            forward ="/listUser.jsp";
            ArrayList<User> myList = new ArrayList<User>();
        myList = userdao.getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("THis List of data arte : " + myList);
        request.setAttribute("users", myList);
```

and error is show that:
 HTTP Status 500 -

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /listUser.jsp at line 33
30:         <tbody>
31:           <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
32:              <tr>
33:                     <td><c:out value="${user.userid}" /></td>
34:                     <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}" /></td>
35:                     <td><c:out value="${user.lastName}" /></td>
36:                     <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" value="${user.dob}" /></td>
```

User.class

```
    package com.d.model;
import java.util.Date;;

public class User {
    private String userid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dob;
    private String email;

    public String getUserid() {

        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(String userid) {

        this.userid = userid;

    }
    /**
     * @return the firstname
     */
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @param firstname the firstname to set
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;

    }
    /**
     * @return the dob
     */
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    /**
     * @param dob the dob to set
     */
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lastname
     */
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @param lastname the lastname to set
     */
    public void setLastname(String lastName) {

        this.lastName = lastName;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userid= " + userid + ", firstName= '" + firstName
                + "', lastName=" + lastName + ", dob=" + dob + ", email="
                + email + "]";
    }    
}
```

Comment: you did not show your stacktrace related to Column 'usrid' not found

Comment: please remove this code and show the present code

Comment: can u plase show exception stacktrace

Comment: you did not changed here   user.setUsrid(rs.getString("userid"));

Answer (score 2):

spelling mistake `setUsrid`.change it setUserid

you are setting `usrid` but you are accessing `userid`

```
user.setUsrid(rs.getString("userid")); //usrid

${user.userid} // userid
```

Comment: thanks PSR , i have use userid instance of usrid so plese give me help and it still give error :Error : GetALLUSER   java.sql.SQLException: Column 'usrid' not found. And if i have used userid so give error that mention in Question.

Comment: @Deval Dholariya can u show me code again and the present error

Comment: @Deval Dholariya see the column name in your database once.Where you changed the name

Comment: table name is : user(userid,firstname,lastname,dob,email)

Comment: change in this line also              user.setUsrid(rs.getString("userid"));  as  user.setUserid(rs.getString("userid"));

Comment: let me know if you have again problem

Comment: i can insert data but can not show that in userlist.jsp reason of jstl error.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'usrid' not found.
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'usrid' not found.

Comment: did you changed this user.setUsrid(rs.getString("userid")).In your code it is not changed

Comment: it does not show data in table and i can see the data in consol by arraylist object but when i pass on jsp page it is not show and it does not show data in table that display lable and ADDUSER link

Comment: so please help so i can i see my data on jsp

Comment: @Deval Dholariya so please post your present code with your present exception by removing all the previous content.Otherwise how i can help

Comment: @David_DD now only you got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

spelling mistake `setUsrid`.change it to `setUserid`

you are setting usrid but you are accessing userid

```
user.setUsrid(rs.getString("userid")); //usrid

${user.userid} // userid
```

Comment: Thanks for give me reply.